# Oracle - Error ORA-00907 using remap_data parameter with datapump export

Tags: oracle, export, datapump

I'm trying to export data with the remap_data parameter (datapump mode) in order to hide some data.

This works fine with "varchar2" or "number" column but fail with "long" column. In the export log file we can see the ORA-31693 error then the ORA-00907 error.

Can anyone please help me with this ? Thanks

Here is my example code :

```
-- data creation
create table TABLE1 (
   COL1         LONG
)
tablespace TAB
/

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1) VALUES ('data1');

COMMIT;

-- package creation
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE hidelong AS
    FUNCTION change_long ( valuetest IN LONG ) RETURN LONG;
END hidelong;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hidelong AS
    LongX LONG := 'XXXXXXXXXX';

    FUNCTION change_long ( valuetest IN LONG ) RETURN LONG IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN LongX;
    END change_long;

END hidelong;
/
```

Export command :

```
expdp system/manager@DB1 schemas=TEST directory=datapump dumpfile=EXP.DMP LOGFILE=EXP.log remap_data=TEST.TABLE1.COL1:hidelong.change_long
```

EXP.log file content :

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mer. Avr. 20 14:56:30 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connecté à : Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Démarrage de "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" : system/********@DB1 schemas=TEST directory=datapump dumpfile=EXP.DMP LOGFILE=EXP.log remap_data=TEST.TABLE1.COL1:hidelong.change_long 
Estimation en cours à l'aide de la méthode BLOCKS ...
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Estimation totale à l'aide le la méthode BLOCKS : 64 KB
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Traitement du type d'objet SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
ORA-31693: Echec du chargement/déchargement de l'objet de données de table "TEST"."TABLE1" ; l'objet est ignoré en raison de l'erreur :
ORA-00907: parenthèse de droite absente
Table maître "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" chargée/déchargée avec succès
******************************************************************************
L'ensemble de fichiers de vidage de SYSTEM.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 est :
  C:\EXP.DMP
Travail "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" terminé avec 1 erreur(s) à 14:57:03
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't mention a restriction on using REMAP_DATA with LONG columns, but as they are restricted in other ways - including not being able to call a function that takes a LONG parameter from SQL, which gets ORA-00997 - it's not entirely surprising it isn't allowed.

There is an Oracle white paper on ["Data Transformations with Oracle Data Pump"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/datapump11g2009-transform-133936.pdf), which includes a section on page 6 on "Special Considerations When Using REMAP_DATA":

> There are other restrictions for the REMAP_DATA parameter that cannot be worked around. ...
>   It also cannot be used for modifying tables that contain columns with the LONG or LONG RAW datatypes.

The message you're getting is unhelpful, and there's a bug (19157986) about the ORA-00907 being misleading. Short of converting your LONG column to a CLOB, there doesn't seem to be a workaround

Anecdotally [it may affect other datatypes as well](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1678103-unable-to-remap_data-varray-type-in-expdp).

Answer (score 0):

As there is no workaround I have to export a different way, for example :

- I will export entire database and exclude TABLE1
- I will create a dump of TABLE1 with :

```
create table TABLE1_ext
  organization external (
    type oracle_datapump
    default directory datapump
    location ('TABLE1.dmp')
  )
as select 'XXXXXXXXXX' as COL1 from TEST.TABLE1;
```

Then I will import these 2 dump files generated.

It would be OK by this way.

Comment: Yes, that would work, if you have a manageable number of tables to handle separately. Your external table presumably will have other columns, otherwise you could just create it manually in the new database. The data type in the external table will also be 'wrong', but you can fix then on import, if you load that .dmp as an external table too and populate the real table from that.